# Trouble coming up with a unique selector in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to get rid of the "Subscribe" header using CSS.

[image]

I inspect it and then I use the following code to remove it and it works fine:

```
#main-outlet.wrap .container .title-wrapper h1 {
    display: none;
}
```

However, it so happens that other elements in my website use this same selector, so it removes them as well. In particular, it removes the titles of the topic discussions on my main page. But I don't know how to fix this because it seems that there isn't a more specific selector for the page with "subscribe" on it in particular. What am I missing?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) **Images of code are not acceptable**

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

You need to isolate your `<h1>` element.

I'm guessing you can't edit the HTML directly, otherwise you'd be able to add a unique `class` to the element.

You can do still isolate the element computationally via a short script.

There are many approaches, but here are two:

#### Approach 1

You can achieve the effect you need with two lines of javascript.

**Javascript**

```
const mainHeading = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
mainHeading.style.setProperty('opacity', 0);
```

---

#### Approach 2

Or, a little more sophisticated, with two lines of javascript and one line of CSS.

**Javascript**

```
const mainHeading = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
mainHeading.classList.add('subscribeMainHeading');
```

**CSS**

```
.subscribeMainHeading {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not working... but that's probably my fault since I'm not too familiar with Javascript and how it interacts with the Discourse software that I use. Is there not a purely CSS solution, a way to isolate that particular <h1> element?

Comment: If neither the `<h1>` element nor its parent, nor any of its ancestors have a unique `class` or `id` or attribute then: no. Something, somewhere needs to be unique, so you can write a unique selector.